# Responsive grid doesn't work with grid-auto-flow: dense

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to setup an image gallery where the images open in a modal box. In my grid I want some of the items to span 2 columns and the smaller items to fill up the spaces, so images 4 and 5 should be up by the side of the first image together with images 2 and 3.

I've tried using grid-auto-flow: dense; but it doesn't seem to work, the smaller items remain on the next row. The grid needs to be responsive. If I just let all items be the same size, they flow down.

```css
body {  
background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat;
background-clip: padding-box; 
margin: 10vh;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20%, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

img {
  width: 100%; 
}

.wrapper img {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: scale(.92)
}

.wrapper img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

h1 {
  font-family: Impact, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.small {
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.large {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>
      Keep calm <br> 
      &amp; travel <br> 
      the world 
    </h1>
  </header>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="large">
      <a href="img/baikal-transsiberian.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Transsiberian railway, Russia">
        <img src="img/baikal-transsiberian-thumb.jpg" alt="Transsiberian railway, Russia">
        
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <a href="img/mongolia.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Mongolia">
        <img src="img/mongolia-thumb.jpg" alt="Mongolia">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <a href="img/kyoto-japan.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Kyoto, Japan">
        <img src="img/kyoto-japan-thumb.jpg" alt="Kyoto, Japan">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <a href="img/bali-indonesia.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Bali, Indonesia">
        <img src="img/bali-indonesia-thumb.jpg" alt="Bali, Indonesia">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <a href="img/lapland-finland.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Lapland, Finland">
        <img src="img/lapland-finland-thumb.jpg" alt="Lapland, Finland">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <a href="img/usa-route66.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Route66, USA">
        <img src="img/usa-route66-thumb.jpg" alt="Route66, USA">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <a href="img/rio-brasil.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Rio de Janeiro, Brasil">
        <img src="img/rio-brasil-thumb.jpg" alt="Rio de Janeiro, Brasil">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="large">
      <a href="img/cuba-havana.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Havana, Cuba">
        <img src="img/cuba-havana-thumb.jpg" alt="Havana, Cuba">
      </a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to define max-width of the container and the size of the rows:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 250px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
```